Chrome Extensions MV3 - Running missed alarms on startup
My Chrome Extension has alarms permission.
During my testing, I set up an alarm in my service-worker (background script) to fetch some data every 10 min. It works as expected.
For the release, I changed my alarm to run every 3 hours. Unfortunately, it does not appear to run every time. (only few users had the alarm run and it was reported they did not close their browsers). I was puzzled why.
After doing a bit of research, I found out that service workers can be unloaded by Chrome as part of Chrome's performance optimizations.

I thought that alarms should cause service to be loaded again. It seems like this is not true.
Others here suggested to implement some functionality to always keep worker up (either by pinging it or having it send HTTP requests, etc). But this does not seem like a good solution.
If there is no way to wake service worker up, I want to implement a functionality to run missed alarms whenever it is loaded back up (whenever users would interact with extension). Is this the best approach or I am missing some fundamentals.

My service-worker.js:
createAlarms() // calls chrome.alarms.create and chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(async () => {
   runMissedAlarms() // get alarm execution times from chrome.storage.local and determine if it was missed
});


You should use chrome.alarms.onAlarm event.
